# set a DockablePane in fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm using AvalonDock 1.3 with .NET 4 on a project, and I have to implement a button in the WPF menu to set a specific DockablePane in fullscreen. I déclare my DockablePane in XAML. I've looked for this on the web without finding anything (except this http://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/242052/ and this http://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/204848?ProjectName=avalondock which don't work with my project). I have already tried to upgrade to AvalonDock 2, but some components are not recognized.

What are your ideas ?